# Laravel Pull Queue

Tags: php, laravel-4, ironmq

I have been using the Laravel framework and have just recently gotten into implementing queue's with Laravel's built in support for IronMQ.

From the Laravel [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#basic-usage) its easy enough to see how to push messages to a queue and then on [Iron.io](http://www.iron.io/) set subscribers and have the queue push to those subscribers. However I want to utilize IronMQ as a Pull queue. I do not see any indication of how to pull a message from a specified queue using Laravel's built in methods.

On the IronMQ site they have all the endpoints listed related to facilitate a Pull queue implementation.

Ex: `/projects/{Project ID}/queues/{Queue Name}/messages`

In the IronMQ package for Laravel I see the methods that seem to work with these endpoints:

```
/**
 * Peek Messages on a Queue
 * Peeking at a queue returns the next messages on the queue, but it does not reserve them.
 *
 * @param string $queue_name
 * @return object|null  message or null if queue is empty
 */
public function peekMessage($queue_name) {
    $messages = $this->peekMessages($queue_name, 1);
    if ($messages == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $messages[0];
    }
}
```

However, I do not see any support for this through Laravel. I would expect to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
$message = Queue::peek();
```

Which would return the next message from a specified queue, etc.

Is there a way to do this with Laravel's built in support that is just not documented?

Thanks!

Edit:

I have seen the documentation on using [Daemon Workers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#daemon-queue-worker) through Laravel, however I want to process the queue myself through a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use IronMQ class instead of laravel Queue class:

```
$ironmq = new \IronMQ(array(
    'token' => Config::get('queue.connections.iron.token', 'xxx'),
    'project_id' => Config::get('queue.connections.iron.project', 'xxx')
));
$ironmq->getMessage($queue_name);
```

[IronMQ PHP lib](https://github.com/iron-io/iron_mq_php)

Comment: Using your suggestion I am able to retrieve a message from the queue, however the body appears to be encrypted in some manner. Excuse my ignorance but I am not sure if this is something Laravel is doing by default, or how i can retrieve the plain text from the message body.

Comment: Crypt was the answer. `$decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($message->body);`